# Shiny app won't display graphs when using an index file

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have been struggling with this problem for days now, all help is much appreciated. 
So I have this shiny app that renders plots using plotly. As long as I don't use an index file for styling the app i works fine (both locally and on the server).

When I use the index-file the plots won't render (the box for the plots are left empty). 
If the app is launched without the index file
`shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)` and then restarted using the index file 
`shinyApp(ui = htmlTemplate("www/index.html"), server)` the plots are rendered temporarily. This works both on the server and locally on my computer, however this "solution" stops working after a while.

My file structure looks like this:

```
 app.R
    www
       index.html
       style.css
```

I have tride with a much simpler app using an index file and in that example it works fine.

The simple example: https://statistik.incanet.se/VHU/ex1

The app without index file: https://statistik.incanet.se/VHU/ex2

The app with index file: https://statistik.incanet.se/VHU/ex3

Note! The graphs are found under "Data och Jämförelser"

I suspect that the link between the index file and app is not established correctly but how do I fix this?

Comment: Hi bayesian_sneeze, upon opening the browser console, it seems like plotly.js and htmlwidgets.js cannot be found in the app with index file. Maybe you need to explicitly load them? It is looking for these files at `htmlwidgets-1.5.1/htmlwidgets.js`, but I think on the app with the index file, this path is relative to this index file, rather than relative to `app.R`.

Comment: Take a look at https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/packaging-javascript.html

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem.